ADFS RefreshToken (SSOLifetime) Not Working
I have gone Through all documentations available from microsoft and every question here in stack overflow.
There is no information as to why would the SSOLifetime setting in AD FS not work or not change the TTL of the refresh token produced by that server.
Regardless of what settings i change, the TTL of the refresh_token is only 60 mins.
I have tried:

Setting the TokenLifeTime of RelyingPartyTrust to any random int, Token is still 60 mins.
Changing the TokenLifeTime in WebApiApplication to any random int, This changed the access_token ttl. (Great Success)
Changing AdfsProperties TokenLifeTime to any random int, Token is still 60 mins.
DeviceUsageWindowInDays is set to 14 days
KMSI is Enabled and set to 30 days. (No effect on tokens what so ever)
BrowserSSO Enabled, BrowserSSO Angents set (No effect on tokens what so ever)
Persistent SSO Enabled, Persistent SSO TokenLifeTime is set to 30 days. (No effect to tokens)

I am requesting the token from a mobile app, written in React-Native using expo.
My only goal is to get the refresh token to live longer then 60 mins.
screen
